# Add class.h and class.cpp to makefile

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

I have created a c++ simple program with one file called plcreate.cpp
and the eclipse has generated the following makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0

OBJS =      pddlProbCreate.o

LIBS =      

TARGET =    pddlProbCreate.exe

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
$(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

all:    $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

I have added this cpddl.h and cpddl.cpp as new class files to the program, but the makefile did not change by eclipse to include the new added files. How can i add the new files manually to make file? or if there is an option in eclipse that can regenerate the make file and consider the new added files?

Answer (score 1):

Just add your file in OBJS var with .o extension

```
CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0

OBJS =      pddlProbCreate.o cpddl.o

LIBS =      

TARGET =    pddlProbCreate.exe

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

all:    $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

Comment: thank you so much, it did work with adding cpddl.o. i m still wondering whether eclipse can regenerate the makefile automatically with the new added classes.

Comment: How can i update this makefile when the .cpp files in folder called source, and .h files in folder called header

Comment: This doesn't handle header file dependencies.

Comment: @WaleedA Look around SO there are any number of make questions about doing that sort of thing.